# How to avoid selecting last item from autocompletetextview

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I am creating simple application where I am having `AutoCompleteTextView` which contains names. I want to load an `ImageView` at the end of last item of AutoCompleteTextView WHICH SHOULD BE NON CLICKABLE/SELECTABLE.

I am able to populate list along with displaying  `ImageView` after last list item HOWEVER, I CANT MAKE IT NON CLICKABLE/SELECTABLE. Means, everytime it selects as a EMPTY field for `AutoCompleteTextView` & sets as a BLANK/EMPTY.

Here, is my `getView()` method code:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (position != (resultList.size() - 1))
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_list_item, null);
        else
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_google_logo, null);

        if (position != (resultList.size() - 1)) {
            TextView autocompleteTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autocompleteText);
            autocompleteTextView.setText(resultList.get(position).getCityDescription());
        }
        else {
            RelativeLayout imageView = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rlTop);
            imageView.setClickable(false);
            imageView.setEnabled(false);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled() + https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#isEnabled(int)

Comment: @Selvin I already override isEnabled() method but not sure how to use it.

Comment: it should be used automagically ... if areAllItemsEnabled returns false

Comment: @Selvin It didn't work automatically. We need to customise it.

Comment: *It didn't work* ... I don't belive, show us how did you tried implement ListAdapter methods.

Comment: @Selvin Given my code in answer. Automatically means without writing any cod coondition

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.

Thanks @Selvin for your comment.

```
@Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if (position != resultList.size() - 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (position != (resultList.size() - 1))
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_list_item, null);
        else
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_logo, null);

            if (position != (resultList.size() - 1)) {
                TextView autocompleteTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autocompleteText);
                autocompleteTextView.setText(resultList.get(position).getName());
            } else {
                RelativeLayout imageView = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rlTop);
            }

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `onTouchListener` on that view, and do nothing in `onTouch()`, just return `true`